# Converting an RGB image into an HSI image without using opencv functions

Tags: c++, image, opencv

I am sort of a beginner when it comes to c++ and opencv.

I have this assignment where i have to successfully convert an image from RGB to HSI and then split the HSI image into the 3 channels Hue, Saturation and respectively Intensity, without using any library functions when implementing my algorithm, after that the 3 images have to be displayed.

I was able to do most of these but when converting from RGB to HSI i am completely lost. From what i saw on other posts the pixel values should be put in a matrix and then changed based on my algorithms, after that the new values should go into a new matrix (HSI).

My main problem (i think) is that i cannot seem to put the values into the new matrix, i tried different methods but the outcome was the same.

Any input is welcome.

Best Regards
Stefan

```
#include <opencv\highgui.h>
#include <opencv\cv.h>
#include <iostream> 
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
Mat rgb;

rgb = imread("Flower.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);

unsigned char *input = (unsigned char*)(rgb.data);

Mat hsi = rgb.clone();

double R,G,B,a,H,S,I;
int  i,j;
const double PI= 3.14;
for(int i = 0;i < hsi.rows ;i++){
    for(int j = 0;j < hsi.cols ;j++){
        B = input[hsi.step * j + i ];
        G = input[hsi.step * j + i + 1];
        R = input[hsi.step * j + i + 2];
    }

    if (R < G && R < B)
        a = R;
    if (G < R && G < B)
        a = G;
    if (B < G && B < R)
        a = B;
    I = (R+G+B)/3.0;
    S = 1 - 3.0/(R+G+B)*a;
    if (S == 0.0)
    {
        H = 0.0;
    }
    else
    {
        if (B <= G)
        H = acos((((R-G)+(R-B))/2.0)/(sqrt((R-G)*(R-G) + (R-B)*(G-B))));
        else
        {
            if (B > G)
            H = 2*PI - acos((((R-G)+(R-B))/2.0)/(sqrt((R-G)*(R-G) + (R-B)*(G-B))));
        }


    }
}

namedWindow("RGB", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
imshow("RGB", rgb);
namedWindow("HSI", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
imshow("HSI", hsi);     

waitKey(0);
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has two problems.

First, you perform calculation outside the second loop:

```
for(int i = 0;i < hsi.rows ;i++){
    for(int j = 0;j < hsi.cols ;j++){
    }
    // HSI calculation
}
```

So, you work only with last pixel in each row.

Second, you don't write results to `hsi` matrix.

Use this code template:

```
Mat bgr = ...; // OpenCV uses BGR format
Mat hsi(bgr.size(), CV_8UC3);
for (int i = 0; i < bgr.rows; ++i)
{
    const Vec3b* bgr_row = bgr.ptr<Vec3b>();
    Vec3b* hsi_row = hsi.ptr<Vec3b>();
    for (int j = 0; j < bgr.cols; ++j)
    {
        double B = bgr_row[j][0];
        double G = bgr_row[j][1];
        double R = bgr_row[j][2];
        double H = ...;
        double S = ...;
        double I = ...;
        hsi_row[j] = Vec3b(H, S, I);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, i managed to make it work using your template but i cannot use any functions when implementing my algorithms so i cannot use 'CV_8UC3'. You gave me an idea tho and i managed to make it work nonetheless.  I will post it as soon as i finish. Thank you